# Batch file: list all folders containing only a file entitled "Thumbs v0.1.db"

Tags: command-line, batch-file, directory, subdirectory

I need to scan through a drive and list all the folders containing only a single file, entitled "Thumbs v0.1.db". I have cobbled together the following code but it doesn't seem to work. Either the batch file exits prematurely, or it completes without listing any such subdirectories! I would be very thankful if someone could point out the problem.

```
@echo off

SET /P folder="Please enter root directory to seach in: "

SET writefile="C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\Thumbs.txt"

SET tmp="C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\rowcounttmp"


Echo Searching for directories, please wait...

echo Thumbs v0.1.db-only directories in %folder% > %writefile%


cd /D %folder%
for /d /r %1 %%A in (.) do (

  dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | find /c /v "~StringWhichWillNotAppear~" > %tmp%

  set var=<%tmp%

  if [%var%] == 1  dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr /i "Thumbs v0.1.db" >nul && echo %%~fA >> %writefile%

)

del %tmp%

Pause
```

Thanks

EDIT:

Thanks to @peter-wright, I now have this: Have I implemented his suggestions incorrectly? It seems to crash for certain filepaths (specifically the read-only drive I am trying to scan through) and there are still no results appearing.

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

Color 0A

SET /P folder="Please enter root directory to seach in: "

SET writefile="C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\Thumbs.txt"

SET tempfile="C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\rowcounttmp"


Echo Searching for directories, please wait...

echo Thumbs v0.1.db only directories in %folder% > %writefile%


cd /D %folder%
for /d /r %1 %%A in (.) do (


  dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | find /c /v "~StringWhichWillNotAppear~" > %tempfile%

  set var=<%tempfile%

  if !var! == 1 dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr /i "Thumbs v0.1.db" >nul && echo %%~fA >> %writefile%

)

del %tempfile%

Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `var` is being set within a BLOCK (parenthesised series of statements.)

Any `%var%` within a block is replaced by the value of that `var` WHEN THE BLOCK IS PARSED, not when it is EXECUTED.

To access the RUN-TIME value of `var` use `!var!` AFTER having invoked `delayedexpansion` with a `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` statement (probably best implemented immediately after your `@echo on`.

**Danger, Will Robinson** : DO not use `tmp` as a variable name - `tmp` is a `magic variable` with special meaning to batch. Others may be listed by invoking

SET

from the prompt. Also avoid DATE, TIME, RANDOM, CD and a few others. And really not a good idea to use executable names or batch keywords either...

tip:

try using

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /a /b /a-d "Thumbs v0.1.db" ') do (
```

and then %%~dpi will be assigned the names of the directories that CONTAIN the target file. If the count-of-files in these directories is not ==1 then it is not alone...

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, I had not considered when the variables might be replaced with their values. (I'm very new to batch files!)

However, it still does not seem to work; no results are returned in the text file when I know there should be! Any further ideas? (The revised code is now in the question)

Comment: Update: Sorry, it seems to crash for certain filepaths (specifically the read-only drive I am trying to scan through), so it seems the error is still present?